# Sending duplicates emails with AWS SES using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I tried to send emails using AWS SES with Java. If I tried to send single Email,it is working fine.If I tried to send more than 4 Email's with different body and emailid.I am getting duplicate mail's. Every mail is receiving 3 times. Please help me how to resolve this duplicate Email issue.

Comment: Can you show your code so that someone can analyse and check what's wrong

Comment: I fixed my issue. Previously I used javax.mail sdk to send emails wtih SES Configuration. Now, I changed jjavax.mail sdk with SES sdk. It's working fine.